# MongoDB running slow with Meteor app. Slow queries, too many queries, multiple connections for same user

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My MongoDB database is running very slowly and I'm having trouble figuring out what is the problem. From the logfile /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log it seems to me that:

1) Queries are taking over 100ms to run even though they are using indexes.

2) The database is being queried continually even though I am only looking at the site, not interacting with it.

3) There seem to be multiple connections listed for a single user.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions or ideas how to figure out what I'm doing wrong and how to lighten the load on my poor server!

System:

METEOR@1.6.0.1 running on a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 16.04)

Deployed using Phusion Passenger 5.2.3

MongoDB version 3.4.1

Here's a typical extract from the logfile:

```
2018-04-25T10:59:07.986+0000 I COMMAND  [conn96] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 36, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:7 nreturned:12 reslen:1536157 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 105ms
2018-04-25T10:59:08.002+0000 I COMMAND  [conn98] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 12, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:8 nreturned:12 reslen:2226386 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 9 } } } protocol:op_query 131ms
2018-04-25T10:59:08.055+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user3_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:83336218087 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:10 nreturned:101 reslen:13408742 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 11 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 11 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 11 } } } protocol:op_query 162ms
2018-04-25T10:59:13.826+0000 I COMMAND  [conn97] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:84388091558 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:9 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 20 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 10 } } } protocol:op_query 167ms
2018-04-25T10:59:16.226+0000 I COMMAND  [conn96] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 48, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:7 nreturned:12 reslen:1812760 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 137ms
2018-04-25T10:59:16.231+0000 I COMMAND  [conn97] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 84, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:7 nreturned:12 reslen:1516442 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 119ms
2018-04-25T10:59:16.237+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:8 nreturned:12 reslen:1671866 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 9 } } } protocol:op_query 149ms
2018-04-25T10:59:16.288+0000 I COMMAND  [conn94] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user2_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85501389604 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:8 nreturned:101 reslen:13271844 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 9 } } } protocol:op_query 187ms
2018-04-25T10:59:18.072+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user3_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:82711174454 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:9 nreturned:101 reslen:13408742 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 20 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 10 } } } protocol:op_query 171ms
2018-04-25T10:59:18.077+0000 I COMMAND  [conn94] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:83227284863 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:8 nreturned:101 reslen:13656126 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 9 } } } protocol:op_query 153ms
2018-04-25T10:59:18.173+0000 I COMMAND  [conn96] command mydb.mycollection command: getMore { getMore: 85501389604, collection: "mycollection", batchSize: 1000 } originatingCommand: { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user2_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85501389604 keysExamined:39 docsExamined:38 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:6 nreturned:38 reslen:7396099 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 7 } } } protocol:op_query 138ms
2018-04-25T10:59:23.882+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 132, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:9 nreturned:1 reslen:852679 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 20 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 10 } } } protocol:op_query 149ms
2018-04-25T10:59:23.958+0000 I COMMAND  [conn94] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85689537829 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:17 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 36 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 18 } } } protocol:op_query 285ms
2018-04-25T10:59:26.235+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 120, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:5 nreturned:12 reslen:2429543 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 6 } } } protocol:op_query 123ms
2018-04-25T10:59:28.007+0000 I COMMAND  [conn97] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 12, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:7 nreturned:12 reslen:2226386 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 124ms
2018-04-25T10:59:28.258+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:84936294363 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:10 nreturned:101 reslen:13656126 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 11 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 11 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 11 } } } protocol:op_query 254ms
2018-04-25T10:59:33.777+0000 I COMMAND  [conn94] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:81855053356 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:7 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 110ms
2018-04-25T10:59:36.212+0000 I COMMAND  [conn96] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 48, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:7 nreturned:12 reslen:1812760 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 104ms
2018-04-25T10:59:36.295+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user2_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:81865981454 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:9 nreturned:101 reslen:13271844 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 20 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 10 } } } protocol:op_query 181ms
2018-04-25T10:59:38.049+0000 I COMMAND  [conn98] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 24, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:8 nreturned:12 reslen:1303021 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 9 } } } protocol:op_query 161ms
2018-04-25T10:59:38.087+0000 I COMMAND  [conn97] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 36, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:9 nreturned:12 reslen:1536157 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 20 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 10 } } } protocol:op_query 199ms
2018-04-25T10:59:38.113+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] }, sort: { name_sort: 1 }, skip: 12, limit: 12 } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } keysExamined:134 docsExamined:133 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:9 nreturned:12 reslen:2226386 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 20 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 10 } } } protocol:op_query 226ms
2018-04-25T10:59:38.300+0000 I COMMAND  [conn94] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:81961357963 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:10 nreturned:101 reslen:13656126 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 11 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 11 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 11 } } } protocol:op_query 327ms
2018-04-25T10:59:43.808+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:81883376628 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:8 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 9 } } } protocol:op_query 143ms
2018-04-25T11:00:03.764+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:83376889974 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:7 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 111ms
2018-04-25T11:00:13.787+0000 I COMMAND  [conn97] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:84784676389 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:6 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 7 } } } protocol:op_query 118ms
2018-04-25T11:00:43.795+0000 I COMMAND  [conn96] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:82406146359 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:6 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 7 } } } protocol:op_query 126ms
2018-04-25T11:00:58.105+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user3_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:82192722075 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:7 nreturned:101 reslen:13408742 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 103ms
2018-04-25T11:01:18.097+0000 I COMMAND  [conn97] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user3_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:84413219787 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:6 nreturned:101 reslen:13408742 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 7 } } } protocol:op_query 111ms
2018-04-25T11:01:23.823+0000 I COMMAND  [conn98] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:82892140473 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:7 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 145ms
2018-04-25T11:02:03.784+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:82310902412 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:5 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 6 } } } protocol:op_query 107ms
2018-04-25T11:02:33.788+0000 I COMMAND  [conn98] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:81823088573 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:5 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 6 } } } protocol:op_query 108ms
2018-04-25T11:02:43.791+0000 I COMMAND  [conn94] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:84344130917 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:7 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 112ms
2018-04-25T11:04:33.821+0000 I COMMAND  [conn98] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85552175444 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:8 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 9 } } } protocol:op_query 127ms
2018-04-25T12:40:14.616+0000 I COMMAND  [conn98] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:83783641075 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:6 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 7 } } } protocol:op_query 106ms
2018-04-25T12:40:28.907+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user3_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:83691420199 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:8 nreturned:101 reslen:13408742 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 9 } } } protocol:op_query 151ms
2018-04-25T12:40:28.932+0000 I COMMAND  [conn97] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { private: { $ne: true } } } planSummary: IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85014875379 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:9 nreturned:101 reslen:13656126 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 20 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 10 } } } protocol:op_query 199ms
2018-04-25T12:40:34.618+0000 I COMMAND  [conn97] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:81942241093 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:7 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 106ms
2018-04-25T12:44:24.658+0000 I COMMAND  [conn94] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:82494645813 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:8 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 9 } } } protocol:op_query 113ms
2018-04-25T12:46:08.743+0000 I COMMAND  [conn97] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user2_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:83393262122 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:7 nreturned:101 reslen:13271844 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 8 } } } protocol:op_query 106ms
2018-04-25T12:46:14.668+0000 I COMMAND  [conn96] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:83287023997 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:6 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 7 } } } protocol:op_query 117ms
2018-04-25T12:46:55.673+0000 I COMMAND  [conn94] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user3_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85500377486 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:4 nreturned:101 reslen:13408742 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 5 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 5 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 5 } } } protocol:op_query 144ms
2018-04-25T12:46:58.776+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user2_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:81656430938 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:8 nreturned:101 reslen:13271844 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 18 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 9 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 9 } } } protocol:op_query 135ms
2018-04-25T12:46:59.117+0000 I COMMAND  [conn98] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user3_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85243285750 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:9 nreturned:101 reslen:13408742 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 20 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 10 } } } protocol:op_query 170ms
2018-04-25T12:47:04.677+0000 I COMMAND  [conn94] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85651420717 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:5 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 6 } } } protocol:op_query 112ms
2018-04-25T12:47:08.745+0000 I COMMAND  [conn95] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user2_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:84542545523 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:5 nreturned:101 reslen:13271844 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 6 } } } protocol:op_query 104ms
2018-04-25T13:36:39.739+0000 I COMMAND  [conn96] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user3_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:83367894125 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:10 nreturned:101 reslen:13408742 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 11 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 11 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 11 } } } protocol:op_query 160ms
2018-04-25T13:36:40.552+0000 I COMMAND  [conn97] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: null } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85829377385 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:5 nreturned:101 reslen:13656126 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 6 } } } protocol:op_query 106ms
2018-04-25T13:36:44.958+0000 I COMMAND  [conn96] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user1_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85645824554 keysExamined:109 docsExamined:101 numYields:5 nreturned:101 reslen:15163185 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 6 } } } protocol:op_query 103ms
2018-04-25T13:37:40.646+0000 I COMMAND  [conn96] command mydb.mycollection command: find { find: "mycollection", filter: { $or: [ { private: { $ne: true } }, { created_by: "user3_id" } ] } } planSummary: IXSCAN { created_by: 1 }, IXSCAN { private: 1 } cursorid:85301123581 keysExamined:101 docsExamined:101 numYields:6 nreturned:101 reslen:13408742 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 7 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 7 } } } protocol:op_query 105ms
```

Here is part of the schema and code that sets up the collection and indexes. There are more fields in the collection in the real code but they are not used in the queries.

```
var Schema = new SimpleSchema({
    'created_at': {
        'type': Number,
        'label': 'Created at',
    },
    'created_by': {
        'type': String,
        'label': 'Created by',
    },
    'private': {
        'type': Boolean,
        'label': 'Private',
        'optional': true,
    },
});

MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('mycollection');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    MyCollection.rawCollection().createIndex( {'created_by': 1} );
    MyCollection.rawCollection().createIndex( {'private': 1} );
    MyCollection.rawCollection().createIndex( {'created_at': -1} );
}

MyCollection.attachSchema(Schema);
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the collection schemas for those collection where the queries are slow?

Comment: Did you configure the deployed app to use Mongo's oplog?

Comment: Hello @MasterAM, no I haven't configured anything to do with oplog. Sadly, I haven't understood what it is or if I should use it (or if I am using it), despite having read the Mongo description.

Comment: @Jankapunkt, thanks I have added an extract from the schema and the code that sets up the collection. It's just one collection which I've called 'mycollection' here.

Comment: @MasterAM, I am still reading about oplog but I find it very confusing and I'm not finding clear information whether it is relevant for an app deployed on a single server, or how to set it up. Can you tell me any more about this or point me at a relevant tutorial?

Comment: It is relevant, doesn't matter what is the deployment scheme. It dictates the publication reactivity model (poll and diff vs oplog tailing). What are you confused about? You should discuss it in the Meteor forums, as SO is not really a discussion platform.

Comment: Thanks @MasterAM, I will try the Meteor forums as you suggest. I am confused about many things...do I have replica sets in my single-server deployment? Do I need replica sets? What is 'tailing'? Why is my database performance so bad when the collections don't have that many records and there aren't many users? What are the oplog queries in my log and why do they take 1000ms? Why do my other queries take over 100ms? Why do I have so many connections for one user? Why is the database being queried continually? I really don't know where to start or what is the root of the problem!

Comment: First, please don't use the comments session for the discussion. You should really take this to the Meteor forums. If you did not setup oplog tailing, you don't have it. It requires a replica set, which can be a single-node replica set. It is a different mode of update, that takes the DB operations and tries to see if they are relevant to an observed publication cursor. Many things may affect your current queries, and I don't think that this on topic here.